# map a sub page of a domain to google sites

Tags: google, redirects, url, cname, google-sites

I control a subpage of a site: `economics.university.edu/summerschool`

I have access to CNAME, etc. However I want to use Google sites to create the site and then map the URL above to my Google site. In other words, someone on the university site that navigated to the summer school page would be redirected to the Google site transparently.

However I keep getting this error from Google: "The format of the web address is unsupported." Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, these instructions will help

> If you own a domain and have access to change the CNAME record, you
>   can map any site created in Google Sites outside of Google Apps (for
>   example, sites.google.com/site) to a custom URL:
>
> Select Manage Site from the More Actions drop-down menu. Click the Web
>   Address tab. Enter your custom URL in the Web Address text box, then
>   click the Add button at the top of the page. For security reasons,
>   your domain must be verified with Google. See the below section,
>   "'Domain is not verified' error when mapping," for details.

For more from this: [click here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/99448?hl=en) then click under the Sites Outside of Google Apps expand button.

Your question seems to imply that you have already pointed your subdomain to the google sites url successfully.